# Google in-page analytics doesn't work in my ASP.NET MVC 3 Razor website

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, google-analytics

We've recently launched a new website http://atlascode.com and since the launch I've been unable to get in-page analytics working on the website.  Google also claims that my tracking code is not working but I think this is a misnomer.

Whenever I attempt to load in-page analytics I receive the error:

We've identified problems in your setup. These may cause problems loading In-Page Analytics.
Your site doesn't load ga.js from Google.

- If you host the Google tracking code on your own servers, it isn't updated automatically and can miss important changes.
- We didn't find a tracking snippet on your site. In-Page Analytics cannot load. Please make sure you have tracking installed correctly. If your snippet is included in a separate JavaScript file, you'll have to manually check it is being loaded correctly.

-ENDS-

I've simply copy and pasted the tracking code on to the website and haven't done anything out of the ordinary.  I've also checked to make sure that under Web Property Settings my Web property name and default URL is atlascode.com.

Any ideas you guys have really would be welcomed.

EDIT: Added screenshot of Google Analytics error http://min.us/mdqlrhj

Thanks in advance

Simon

Comment: Try viewing it in `Full Screen Mode`. Also, check to make sure you don't have any sort of script blocker on. If the `atlascode.com` can't load all the scripts (the ones that analytics loads like ones from gstatic.com, and google.com) then it will fail.

Answer (score 1):

Well there's whole buncha people in the web complaining about the same issue.
I've noticed something funny.

Most of developers love to exclude `Analytics` tracking code for logged in administrators and trying to check out `In-Page Analytics` while they're logged in. So there's really no any `ga.js`.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, this occurred when I hadn't set my default URL to exactly match the URL set in the profile.

Matt

P.S. Someone beat me to your source!

Comment: :) Thanks Matt I think I've already set this accordingly? See screenshot. http://i.imgur.com/PWorx.png. www.atlascode.com redirects to atlascode.com

Comment: Just thought that it could be because of the url format in MVC. Take a look at http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?answer=178902&topic=15336&hl=en_US under "troubleshooting" > "default page"

Comment: I''ve narrowed it down.  I'm performing a rewrite using IIS 7.5 URL Rewrite module to permanently redirect http://www.atlascode.com to http://atlascode.com. When I remove this the in page analytics works perfectly. So it's something to do with this but I'm still trying to work out how to fix it.

Comment: Take a look at http://www.google.com/support/analyticshelp/bin/answer.py?answer=1012243

Comment: Sorry if I'm being slow Matt but I don't see how that's related?

Comment: Ok I think I know what this is.  When I first created the account for my site I set its URL to www.atlascode.com.  I went back later and updated the URL as described. Giving up on everything else I created a new account in Google Analytics for http://atlascode.com and checked back a few days later and the new one just works.  I think it's a bug in Google Analytics.  Thanks for all your help Matt.

Comment: I was in the process of setting up Google Analytics with a redirect to find the solution, but I'm glad it has sorted for you. Well done!

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem on Magento Enterprise, but solution was pretty simple: GA code just need to be placed before `<head>` tags. After this simple fix In-Page tracking works perfectly.

*Update*

Also, be sure you have no framekiller installed in your site.